# Accessing RichTextBox in Multi-threaded application causes OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, msmq

I am probably just doing it very wrong. I am currently working with MSMQ and Webservices. I wanted to learn how MSMQ worked so I found a school example of a Loan Broker.

To make a long story short, I need to be able to stress test my system, so I want to be able to make, say, 100 messages and send them through my messaging system. I want to do that from a Windows Form application, but here lies the problem. I have a form that looks like this:

[image: main form]

On the left you see a custom control and on the right, my "console" window that tells me what's going on. When I press the Send button, it should use the data given in the fields above it, to send messages. But when I press the Send Button, the program freezes for a while and then hits the `OutOfMemoryException`. This is the `Send` method:

```
private void Send(List<SimpleRequest.LoanRequest> list)
{
    int quantity = int.Parse(numericQuantity.Value.ToString());
    int delay = int.Parse(numericDelay.Value.ToString());

    if (list.Count == 1)
    {
        for (int threadnumber = 0; threadnumber < quantity; threadnumber++)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RequestLoanQuote(threadnumber, list[0]));
            if (delay > 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(delay);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int threadnumber = 0; threadnumber < quantity; threadnumber++)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RequestLoanQuote(threadnumber, list[threadnumber]));
            if (delay > 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(delay);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `RequestLoanQuote` method that the `Send` method is calling:

```
private void RequestLoanQuote(object state, SimpleRequest.LoanRequest loanRequest)
{
    try
    {
        if (console.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetText("Sending: " + loanRequest.SSN + "\n");
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var threadnumber = (int)state;
        using (var client = new LoanBrokerWS.LoanBrokerWSClient())
        {
            Utility_Tool.LoanBrokerWS.LoanQuote response = client.GetLoanQuote(loanRequest.SSN, loanRequest.LoanAmount, loanRequest.LoanDuration);
            sb.Append(response.SSNk__BackingField + " returned: ");
            sb.Append(response.interestRatek__BackingField + " | ");
            sb.Append(response.BankNamek__BackingField + "\n");
            SetText(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        SetText(e.Message + "\n");
    }
}
```

And finally, the `SetText` method:

```
private void SetText(String msg)
{
    if (this.console.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { msg });
    }
    else
    {
        this.console.Text += msg;
    }
}
```

So the `Send` method calls the `RequestLoanQuote` method which calls the `SetText` method. I cannot figure out where I went wrong but it's probably a deadlock.

Comment: `this.console` is the `RichTextBox`, right?  Try using [`this.console.AppendText(msg)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Also, try using [`BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `Invoke`.

Comment: @dbc Thank you that did the trick. Would you like to make it an answer instead? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`AppendText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like so:

```
    public static void SetText(this RichTextBox textBox, string msg)
    {
        Action append = () => textBox.AppendText(msg);

        if (textBox.InvokeRequired)
            textBox.BeginInvoke(append);
        else
            append();
    }
```

Comment: There is one problem though. It doesn't seem to start all the threads as expected. If I tell it to start 10 requests, it might start 5 first then the other 5 or any random number of the remaining requests. Not sure what I am doing wrong or if that would be expected due to multi-threading.

Comment: @Vipar - not my area of expertise, but you're actually creating a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), right?  I believe that a `Task` is actually a very lightweight object and will be assigned to run on some Thread (a heavier object) when one is free.  Perhaps ask a second, more focused question?

Comment: I could try that. Thanks for trying though :)